# Different Approach to the following ASP.NET Web API Action

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, asp.net-web-api

Maybe someone here can help me sort out this implementation and make it better.

First the following constraints:

- 1 Controller & Action that accepts all post requests, these post requests will always be XML data but can be different in the sense that the elements and the element count can differ.
- Each type of incoming XML has different rules that apply to what the system should do once a request comes in with that type of XML

Here is some code as an example, my implementation is ugly and I am hoping someone can help with making it better, and or showing me an ASP.NET Web API feature that could help with this.

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage message)
{
    try
    {
        var content = message.Content;

        string messageContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        _logger.Info("Incomming Request: " + messageContent);

        var testSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MessageType));
        XmlReader testReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(messageContent));
        var msgType = (MessageType)testSer.Deserialize(testReader);

        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.Message.Common.TextMessage));

        var customer = _uow._customer.Single(u => u.OAWeChatID.Equals(msgType.ToUserName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (customer == null)
        {
            var error = _uow._errorLogs.Create(new DAL.Model.ErrorLog { Message = string.Format("Customer with OA ID {0} could not be found", msgType.ToUserName), Type = "Not found" });
            _uow.commit();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        if (customer.CustomAssembly == null)
        {
            handler = new Handler(_logger, Request, _uow);
        }
        else
        {
            handler = ExtractPluginFromAssembly(customer.CustomAssembly);
        }

        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(messageContent));

        if (msgType.MsgType.Equals("Text", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var textMessage = (Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.Message.Common.TextMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            return await handler.HandleTextMessage(textMessage);
        }
        else
        {
            serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.Message.Common.ImageMessage));
            if (msgType.MsgType.Equals("Image", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var imageMessage = (Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.Message.Common.ImageMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            else
            {
                serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.Message.Common.AudioMessage));
                if (msgType.MsgType.Equals("Voice", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var audioMessage = (Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.Message.Common.AudioMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                }
                else
                {
                    serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.Message.Common.VideoMessage));
                    if (msgType.MsgType.Equals("Video", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                    {
                        var videoMessage = (Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.Message.Common.VideoMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LocationDataMessage));
                        if (msgType.MsgType.Equals("Location", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                        {
                            var locationDataMessage = (LocationDataMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LinkMessage));
                            if (msgType.MsgType.Equals("Link", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                            {
                                var linkMessage = (LinkMessage)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(FollowingEvent));
                                if (msgType.MsgType.Equals("Event", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                {

                                    var eventSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(EventType));
                                    XmlReader eventReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(messageContent));
                                    var eventType = (EventType)eventSer.Deserialize(eventReader);

                                    if (eventType.Event.Equals("subscribe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        var followingEvent = (FollowingEvent)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                                        return await handler.HandleFollowingEvent(followingEvent);
                                    }
                                    else if (eventType.Event.Equals("unsubscribe", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        var followingEvent = (FollowingEvent)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                                        return await handler.HandleFollowingEvent(followingEvent);
                                    }
                                    else if (eventType.Event.Equals("location", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ReportingLocationEvent));
                                        if (serializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
                                        {
                                            var reportingLocationEvent = (ReportingLocationEvent)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if (eventType.Event.Equals("click", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TextMessageEvent));
                                        if (serializer.CanDeserialize(reader))
                                        {
                                            var textMessageEvent = (TextMessageEvent)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
                                            return await handler.HandleClickEvent(textMessageEvent);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    return message.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return message.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logError(new DAL.Model.ErrorLog
        {
            Message = ex.ToString(),
            Type = "Exception"
        });
        _logger.Error(ex.ToString());
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
}
```

Example xml:

```
<xml>
    <enentType>click</eventType>
    <fromUserId></fromUserId>
    <toUserId></toUserId>
</xml>
```

The classes used for the de-serialize are all sizable with the XML root being specified.

Answer (score 2):

First you need a serializer class for serialize and deserializer method

```
public class Serializer
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string message)
    {
        var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(message))
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stringReader))
            {
                return (T)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you need to ContentHandler which will handle all the call (above if else is not required)

```
public class ContentHandler
{
    public enum MessageTypes
    {
        Text,
        Image,
        Voice,
        Video,
        Location,
        Link,
        Suscribe
    }

    public async Task<Content> Process(MessageTypes messageType)
    {
        switch (messageType)
        {
             case MessageTypes.Text:
                 var textMessage=Serializer.Deserialize<Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.Message.Common.TextMessage>(messageContent);
                return await handler.HandleImageMessage(textMessage);

            case MessageTypes.Voice:
                 var voiceMessage=Serializer.Deserialize<Strikemedia.Api.WeChat.Message.Common.VoiceMessage>(messageContent);
                 return await handler.HandleVoiceMessage(voiceMessage);

           //TODO other cases

        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

}
```

Then your refactored method, I am processing on the basis of the message types.

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post(HttpRequestMessage message)
    {
        var content = message.Content;
        string messageContent = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var msgType = Serializer.Deserialize<MessageType>(messageContent);

        var customer = _uow._customer.Single(u => u.OAWeChatID.Equals(msgType.ToUserName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));

        if (customer == null)
        {
            var error = _uow._errorLogs.Create(new DAL.Model.ErrorLog { Message = string.Format("Customer with OA ID {0} could not be found", msgType.ToUserName), Type = "Not found" });
            _uow.commit();
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        if (customer.CustomAssembly == null)
            handler = new Handler(_logger, Request, _uow);
        else
            handler = ExtractPluginFromAssembly(customer.CustomAssembly);


        var contentHandler = new ContentHandler();
        var response=  await contentHandler.Process((ContentHandler.MessageTypes) msgType.MsgType);

        return message.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    }
```

One more tip for , reading the content from the HttpRequestMessage you could user some model binder , I did not find any async version of the code though so you might need to look for it.

Comment: `StringReader` and `XmlReader` both implement `IDisposable` and therefore should be properly deterministically disposed by employing `using` constructs.

Comment: true ,sorry forgot to implement dispose thing

Answer (score 1):

Much of your posted code is just unneeded. Note I am refering to the `else` part of theis `if` statement

> ```
> if (msgType.MsgType.Equals("Text", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
> ```

You are creating objects and you are doing nothing with them like

```
var imageMessage = ..
var audioMessage = ..
var videoMessage = ..
```

As I guess `MessageType` is an enum, why don't you use the enum and a `switch` statement ?
Also, create the `serializer` object at the time you know that the condition is true.
You should refactor this whole `if..else` monster to a separate method using the described way above.